# Can I put a Java class with no package in a different directory?

Tags: java

I inherited all these classes that have no package, and the only way I can make this work is to put all these in the root directory where I run my class program. The issue is that this pollutes the directory and it's not a clean installation. Since these classes were already compiled, I cannot change the package. Is there a way to put these classes in a directory and have Java find them in the classpath?

Comment: The `java` command has a `-cp` option.

Comment: (And to be pedantic, you *could* package them using byte code manipulation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have them only as bytecode, you are using them more or less like a libray. So why not generate a jar file out of them?

```
jar cf jar-file-name input-files-or-dirs-with-wildcard
```

Then you can put this jar-file wherever you want, you just need to add it to your classpath and your root-directory is no longer polluted.